# Applying lambda funtion in Regex

Tags: regex, text, lambda, numbers, decomposition

I have a sentence including text and number values. I want to have a decomposition of the number.

```
s = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog 123.456"
```

Expected results:

```
"the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog 1_hundreds 2_tens 3_ones 4_tenths 5_hundredths 6_thousandths"
```

I successfully apply the decomposition function:

[image]

Then, I apply the lambda function in regex. Unfortunately, I got an error as follows. Please help me on that. Thanks!

[image]

All the code as follows:

```
vital_sign_values = [('thousands', 1000), ('hundreds', 100), ('tens', 10), 
                     ('fives', 5), ('ones', 1), ('tenths', 0.1), ('hundredths', 0.01), ('thousandths', 0.001)]


def decoding_digits(num):

    num = float(num)

    num = int(num * 1000)

    num = float(num) / 1000

    output_dict = {}
    for place, value in vital_sign_values:
        output_dict[place] = num // value
        num = num % value
    
    result = [str(int(v))+"_"+k for k,v in output_dict.items() if v!=0]
    
    return(result)

numeric_decode = decoding_digits(123.456)

import re

from functools import partial

s = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog 123.456"
 
vital_number = re.compile(r"([0-9]+([,.])+([0-9]+)?)")

result = vital_number.sub(partial(decoding_digits), s)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re%20sub#re.sub) passes a match object to the callback, and your `decoding_digits` function expects a string. You can pass the matched string from the match object instead by using a lambda function e.g.

```
result = vital_number.sub(lambda m:decoding_digits(m.group()), s)
```

Also, `decoding_digits` returns a list, not a string. You can fix that by changing

```
return(result)
```

to

```
return ' '.join(result)
```

Final code:

```
vital_sign_values = [('thousands', 1000), ('hundreds', 100), ('tens', 10), 
                     ('fives', 5), ('ones', 1), ('tenths', 0.1), ('hundredths', 0.01), ('thousandths', 0.001)]

def decoding_digits(num):
    num = float(num)
    num = int(num * 1000)
    num = float(num) / 1000

    output_dict = {}
    for place, value in vital_sign_values:
        output_dict[place] = num // value
        num = num % value
    
    result = [str(int(v))+"_"+k for k,v in output_dict.items() if v!=0]
    return ' '.join(result)

import re

s = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog 123.456"
 
vital_number = re.compile(r"([0-9]+([,.])+([0-9]+)?)")

result = vital_number.sub(lambda m:decoding_digits(m.group()), s)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog 1_hundreds 2_tens 3_ones 4_tenths 5_hundredths 6_thousandths
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @Nick. The problem was perfectly solved.